# jquery date picker not working through php includes

Tags: jquery, include, datepicker

My index file contains layout code that doesn't change on any page.  Where the content of the page is displayed, i used GET vars to determine which php file to include.  Whenever I put in a jquery date picker (http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), the $("ID_Name").datepicker(); call doesn't execute.

Here's what I'm doing:
    ./index.php
        ./pages/createJob.php
            ./pages/dealerships.php

So the user is loading index first, then createJob.php, which then calls dealerships.php.

I have the following in the head of index.php:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I then have this in dealerships.php:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('foo');
        $(function() {
            $("#dealershipSaleStartDate").datepicker();
        });
        alert('bar');
    });
</script>
<input id="dealershipSaleStartDate" type="text" />
```

When the page loads, i get the "foo" alert, but not the "bar" alert.  Can I not reference a function that's not explicitly in the specific file?  Doesn't seem right, but it's the only thing I can think of...

Comment: why u call two times jquery library

Comment: why have you included jquery twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need two doumnet.ready function there..remove one

```
<script>
  //$(document).ready(function() {
    //alert('foo');
    $(function() {  //<--this is shorthand of document.ready function
        alert('bar');
        $("#dealershipSaleStartDate").datepicker();
    });

  //});
</script>
```

Comment: it's saying TypeError: #(...).datepicker is not a function.  Looked it up, found another link to the jquery library. I removed it, and now it works just fine.  Thanks!